# How to share folder between Linux PCs?

Tags: linux, debian, network-shares

I've 2 linux PCs and i would like to share a folder between them. 
The 2 linux PCs are Debian derivatives (one knoppix, the other linux mint debian).

Can someone explain how to setup the knoppix machine to share a folder with the other.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sshfs if you want an ad-hoc solution

Answer (score 3):

You could either do it the 'Windows' way and install [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) to share out some folders, or you could use [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29) to do it the proper Unix way.

Comment: With an in-kernel CIFS client, Samba isn't a bad choice. IMHO, better than NFSv3.

Comment: Everything else seems to use CIFS these days, so why not follow the crowd?

Answer (score 1):

I usually keep files synced between my Linux, Windows and Android devices by using Dropbox.

It may be a dirty solution, but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a network file system eg AFS, though that might be overkill. Have you considered a separate file server?
Personally I'd use version control (git, mercurial) and sync from a remote repository, unless your files are too large to manage that way.